# Adding data to traces with suplots mantaining data split for each subplot in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the dummy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,20,30,40],'B':['Tita','Tita','Tita','Burru','Burru','Burru'],'Z':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

I would like to have a subplot for each value in column B (Tita and Burru).

This code produces the expected output:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
lista_syst=df.B.unique()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df.loc[df['B'] == 'Tita', 'A'], y=df.loc[df['B'] == 'Tita', 'Z']),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df.loc[df['B'] == 'Burru', 'A'], y=df.loc[df['B'] == 'Burru', 'Z']),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

[image]

But I would like to make it automatic for **n** possible values in column B like this:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,20,30,40],'B':['Tita','Tita','Tita','Burru','Burru','Burru'],'Z':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
lista_syst=df.B.unique()
for sist in lista_syst:
    print(sist)
    print(df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'A'])
    for i in range(1,3):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(y=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'A'],x=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'Z']),
            row=1,col=i

        )
```

This last code, returns two duplicated graphs with all the values (Same graph twice for both values in B), how so?

[image]

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,20,30,40],'B':['Tita','Tita','Tita','Burru','Burru','Burru'],'Z':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
lista_syst=df.B.unique()

for sist in lista_syst:
    print(sist)
    print(df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'A'])
    fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'Z'],
                y=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'A']))
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

This gives you:
[image]

**Edit after comment:**
If you want individual graphs next to each other, then you can do something like:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,20,30,40],'B':['Tita','Tita','Tita','Burru','Burru','Burru'],'Z':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
lista_syst=df.B.unique()
i=0
for sist in lista_syst:
    i=i+1
    fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'A'],y=df.loc[df['B'] == sist, 'Z']),
            row=1,col=i
        )
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

This gives you:
[image]

Comment: Not really, I want something like the output in my first graph example, will add screenshot.

Comment: I have corrected my answer please have a look. You want your first graph type with all the scatter plots in one graph or you want multiple graphs?

Comment: Please check my updated answer if you need multiple graphs.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. I can't check in detail now but will take a look of what's different in your graph.
Ok jus realized i'm iterating over my list and then the counter (i) to get the position of the graphs, thanks again.